# $\pi(\beta,\sigma^2)l(\beta,\sigma^2\vert Y)\iff\pi(\sigma^2\vert Y)\pi(\beta\vert\sigma^2, Y)?$

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, posterior

How do you pass from $$\pi(\beta,\sigma^2\vert Y)\propto\pi(\beta,\sigma^2)l(\beta,\sigma^2\vert Y)$$ to $$\pi(\beta,\sigma^2\vert Y)\propto\pi(\sigma^2\vert Y)\pi(\beta\vert\sigma^2, Y)$$

?

I know one needs to use the multiplicative law of probability: $P(A\cap B)=P(B\vert A)P(A)$

I tried to apply to the prior

$P(\beta,\sigma^2)=P(\sigma^2\vert\beta)P(\beta)$ though does not looks too much like $\pi(\sigma^2\vert Y)\pi(\beta\vert\sigma^2, Y)$

Comment: Set $Y$ as fixed, the two expressions are then the two versions of marginal x conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit in trying to pass through the first equation.  Proceeding directly using the rules of conditional probability gives you:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\pi(\beta,\sigma^2\vert Y)
&= \frac{p(\beta,\sigma^2, Y)}{p(Y)} \\[6pt]
&= \pi(\beta|\sigma^2, Y) \cdot \frac{p(\sigma^2, Y)}{p(Y)} \\[6pt]
&= \pi(\beta|\sigma^2, Y) \cdot \pi(\sigma^2 \vert Y) \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Note that this result does not depend on any prior assumptions - it is a direct consequence of the rules of conditional probability.